# dt.load(cmd.ExecuteReader) object reference not set to an instance of the object

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, ms-access-2007

I am tying to load data in an Access database into a Datatable in WinForms
but the error **"object reference not set to an instance of the object"** comes on the 6the line of code **dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)**.

```
       Call connect()
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from Items_List_Table where GRF_No=" & Lbl_Grf_No.Text - 1, con)
        MsgBox(Lbl_Grf_No.Text)
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader) 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        Dim row_count As Integer
        row_count = dt.Rows.Count()
        con.Close()
```

[image: This is a picture of the database]

This is the access database. GRF_NO, Item_Unique_Code and Item_Shop_Code are number types. All others are texts.

Comment: The Lbl_Grf_No.Text - 1 result is 18
So I am searching for rows that has GRF_No 18

Comment: Your datatable is not initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instantiating the variable like this

Dim dt As New DataTable()